# Передача файла на другой сервер

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Здравствуйте. Связал между собой два сервера, для бередачи файлов через .sh скрипт.

Создал файл test.sh с содержанием:

```
scp -P 22 /file/my_file.conf root@IP_SERVER:/folder/file.txt
```

Если запускать этот файл через Shell клиент командой: `sh /folder/test.sh`
файл передается на сервер, но открыть этот файл невозможно, он битый.

А если просто выполнить команду в  Shell клиент: `scp -P 22 /file/my_file.conf root@IP_SERVER:/folder/file.txt` - файл передается и как нужно, не битый.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: для начала я бы сравнил размеры файлов. Возможно, файл просто не передается до конца

Comment: @KoVadim возможно и так. но почему он не передается до конца? ведь если просто выполнить команду на передачу файла - он передается правильно. а если запускать файл в котором прописаны команды на передачу файлов - он передает битые фалы...

Comment: так команды или команда? вполне возможно, что передается много-много файлов и где то все таки срабатывает таймаут.

Comment: @KoVadim изначально было 5 команд на передачу файлов. я тоже думал что в дело в этом, но нет, убрал все команды кроме одной - результат тот же. да и файлы там по 2кб размером

Comment: ок, продолжим угадывать:) а если запустить скрипт не через sh, а через bash? и запускается это все в терминале или чем то другом (кроне к примеру)

Comment: @KoVadim впервые сталкиваюсь с .sh скриптами и линуксом. у меня на сервере есть только Shell клиент и  я через него запускаю выполнение файла `sh /folder/test.sh`

Comment: @Денис попробуй через `bash  /folder/test.sh`

Comment: scp использует запуск sftp, если не получается, то катом гонит.. видать что-то не сошлось)

Comment: конечно, хотелось бы увидеть разницу между этими файлами, но если оно перешло на cat, то может там проявилась каким то образом проблема перевода строк?